# How to remove image, then blit it again?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game with pygame and I ran into a problem. My game is a space game: there are meteors coming at you, you have to dodge them and you can also shoot missles at them. When the missles hit the meteors, I want to make the missle dissapear and the meteor to be reset back where it started falling. I saw a line of code that showed how to make an image transparent, by doing this:

```
transparant = (0,0,0,0)
#Code in between
missle.image = missleImg
#I wrote some code to see if the missle was touching a meteor
missle.image.fill(transparent)
```

However, when I try to shoot the missle again, it is still transparent. Does anybody have a better way to unblit and the reblit an image?

Comment: You shouldn't make it transparent, but instead just stop blitting it. Then when the player is firing the missile again, you start rendering it again. Transparency should be used to make things see-through, not to hide images/sprites.

Comment: How should I stop blitting it? The only way I found was making it transparent

Comment: By stop blitting with `screen.blit(image, position)`. It's hard to give a concrete answer without knowing your current code, but you should have a game loop that clears the screen at the beginning of the loop and then draws everything in. Usually you have a list (or group) of things to blit, and when you want it to "die" or disappear you remove it from the list. When you want it to reappear/respawn again you add it to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lists or groups to organize the objects. Create one list or groups to for the meteors and another list or group for the missiles. When a missile hits a meteor, remove the objects from the container. Create new objects when you need them:

If the meteor immediately appears in a different position, it is sufficient to change the meteor's position attribute rather than destroying an object and creating a new one.

e.g. [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
meteor_group = pygame.sprite.Group():
missile_group = pygame.sprite.Group():
```

```py
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(meteor_group, missile_group, True, True)
```

e.g. lists:

```py
meteor_list = []:
missile_list = []:
```

```py
for meteor in meteor_list[:]:
    for missile in missile_list[:]:

        collide = # [...] check for collision 
        if collide:
            meteor_list.remove(meteor) 
            missile_list.remove(missile)
```

Comment: What does groupcollide do in the third line of code?

Comment: @NikiGholipour See the documentation [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). Note, the code in the question is just an example. I can not guess your code. I thought you are using `pygame.sprite.Sprite`.

Comment: Thank you, I am not using sprite I loaded images instead. Should I still try using your example or will it not work without sprites?

Comment: @NikiGholipour It's up to you. I've extended the answer.